# ggplot2 grid.export plot size SVG

Tags: r, svg, ggplot2, size, scale

How can I specify the width and height of the final SVG when I do:

```
print(plot)
saveXML(grid.export()$svg)
```

I'm producing plots for a web application in SVG. I was using ggplot2 and saving the plot using `ggsave` which allowed me to specify size in inches for width and height. I worked great. I now needed to perform annotations on the SVG and it seemed that `ggsave` did not work, so I'm forced to use the grid.export approach presented above. The only aspect I seem to have control is the resolution, which allows me to make plots smaller. However, while `ggsave` made all the text and point size scale to a bigger size, the `grid.export` approach changing the resolution can make the plot smaller, but just by makes everything smaller so the plot reads worse.

For instance, setting `width` and `height` to `3`

`ggsave` version:

[image: img]

`grid.export` version:

[image: img]

Comment: Thanks nejc, ggsave works as I needed in this regard, but didn't seem to work for me for other reasons (the annotations I hacked in didn't work).

Comment: The problem with ggsave is that, for instance when using geom_point, instead of producing the grobs, garnished with my stuff, it produces paths, ungarnished. Otherwise its faster and has a better look at the end. I think I'll inquire about that in another post

Comment: @MiguelVazquez Convention here is to put your solution as an answer (self-answering questions is quite acceptable), not to edit the question with the answer. You can then accept your answer to indicate that the problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I managed to do is define a new base_size on the theme to compensate the resolution scaling:

```
base.size = 10 * (7/size)
resolution = 72 * (size/7)

if (length(plot$theme) == 0) plot <- plot + theme_gdocs();

plot$theme$text$size = base.size

mysvg <- grid.export(res=resolution)
```